# Deleting files locally but not from Github

Tags: github

I am somewhat new to Github, but I have connected a file path to my Github Desktop and simply download and push files from there. I am looking for a way to upload a lot of files to Github, delete them locally to decrease storage capacity, and continue to upload files to the same repo.

Right now, when I go to commit new uploads, I have to deselect all of the files I have deleted as to not delete them from Github, but I wanted to see if there was an easier method to do this in bullk.